# Updating JSON Array Property In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Microsoft SQL server, and I have a variable in SQL that contains a JSON array. Now, I am trying to update one property and set it to 0 for all the JSON objects inside the JSON array.

I have tried the following query, but it just updates the first JSON object.

```
DECLARE @Json varchar(MAX), @updatedJson varchar(MAX);
SET @Json ='[{"LocationID":1234,"LocationName":"ABCD","MTML":1},{"LocationID":12345,"LocationName":"LMNO","MTML":3}]'
SET @updatedJson = JSON_MODIFY(@Json, '$[0].MTML', 0);
SELECT @updatedJson;
```

I know that I can add one more statement like:

```
SET @updatedJson = JSON_MODIFY(@updatedJson, '$[1].MTML', 0);
```

to the above query and update the second JSON object. But I would like to see some suggestions to do this in a generic way and not for specific array elements.

Would highly appreciate any help!

Comment: If you search the site, you'll find enough solutions to your problem. A possible approach is a statement like this: `SELECT @updatedJson = CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(JSON_MODIFY([value], '$.MTML', 0), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key])), ']') FROM OPENJSON(@Json)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `OPENJSON` that parses JSON text and returns objects and properties from the JSON input as rows and columns and `JSON_MODIFY` to update each object individually, then `STRING_AGG` to build the updated JSON

```
SELECT @updatedJson = CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(JSON_MODIFY([value], '$.MTML', 0), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key])), ']') 
FROM OPENJSON(@Json);
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Kwpb1YHQ)

Comment: This will change a single item in the input JSON array.